# Adding multiple (cluster) labels on basemap

Tags: pandas, label, cluster-analysis, k-means, matplotlib-basemap

Here is my code for applying the KMeans clustering algorithm on the UK for my dataset (into 2 clusters). On the line `clusters = m.scatter(etc,..)`, I want to be able to label both of the clusters. Likewise, on the line `cog = m.scatter(etc,..)`, I want to have the respective labels "CoG Cluster 1" AND "CoG Cluster 2".

I have tried some sort of looping, but it still seems to only plot 1 of the labels.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='h', 
        lat_0=54.7, lon_0=-3.36,
        width=0.7E6, height=1.2E6)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

#load locations
X = pd.read_csv("123.csv")

lat = X['Latitude'].values
lon = X['Longitude'].values

#apply the KMeans Clustering Algorithm and plot clusters
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, algorithm ='full')
km.fit(X)

# review the cluster labels, save them, and sort by cluster
X['cluster'] = km.labels_

# save the DataFrame of cluster centers
centers = X.groupby('cluster').mean()

# create a "colors" array for plotting
import numpy as np
cluster_colors = np.array(['green','blue'])
centroid_colors = np.array(['black','orange'])

# scatter plot colored by cluster (1=green, 2=blue)
clusters = m.scatter(lon, lat, latlon=True, c=cluster_colors[X.cluster], s=80, alpha=0.8,label="Cluster 2")

#plot centre of gravity for each cluster (unweighted)
cog = m.scatter(centers['Longitude'].values, centers['Latitude'].values, latlon=True, marker='s', alpha=0.8, s=200, c=centroid_colors[X.cluster],label="CoG Cluster 1")

plt.legend(frameon=True,facecolor='white',handles=[cog,clusters])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want to achieve (in terms of marker shape and color), but maybe you could just generate your own legend. Have a look at the last example on this [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) on how to do that.

Comment: There should be a way of looping over the labels in the clusters line and the cog line, so that I wouldn't need to create my own legend?

Comment: But you are only creating two labels (two calls to `scatter`). If you want all the labels directly, you will have to plot your clusters separately. And again if you don't want *that*, you'll have to add the labels 'by hand'.